# Reference request: Sheaf for the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, schemes

[In my course notes page 62](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Eschraen/CoursM2/Cours.pdf) I've read the following: let $(E,0)$ be an elliptic curve over an arbitrary scheme $S$, then $U\rightarrow\ker(\,0^*_U:\operatorname{Pic}(E_U)\rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(U))$ is a sheaf for the Zariski topology.

What is "sheaf for the Zariski topology" ? So far I know what is a sheaf and what is Zariski topology. I'll be thankful for any references in this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a sheaf $\cal F$ with values in a category $\mathbf{C}$ on any topological space $X$ by letting ${\cal F}(U)$ be an object in $\mathbf{C}$ for any open set $U\subset X$ so that the usual axioms are met.

E.g. see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)).

To fix ideas you may think that $\mathbf{C}$ is the category of groups, so that ${\cal F}(U)$ is a group for every open $U\subset X$ and the restriction maps
$$
\rho_{U,V}:{\cal F}(V)\longrightarrow{\cal F}(U)
$$
will be homomorphisms for every inclusion $U\subset V$ of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, a sheaf is defined on open sets and the Zariski topology is a choice of open sets. So a "sheaf for the Zariski topology" is an assignment of groups/modules/rings etc. (Picard groups in your case) to Zariski-open sets of the top space in a way that compatible sections glue uniquely.